# Phonegap/cordova connection.type

Tags: android, cordova

I have a problem with connection.type on cordova '2.9.0-0-g83dc4bd'

I have the following function:

```
function checkConnection() {
     var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
   alert(networkState);
}
```

when I call the "checkConnection" function, if the device is connected to internet, the function print the message WIFI/3G; but, if the device is not connected to internet it does not print anything. I was expecting a "NONE" message but nothing happens.

I'm developing for Android using Eclipse, and when this happens, the logcat don't shows anything related with this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
function check_network(){


    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';

    return states[networkState];


}
```

Comment: It was my bad, I was calling another method before checkConnection(); that method was trying to access the network. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

```
   function checkConnection() {
         var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
          if (networkState  == 'none') { //Connection.NONE   
            //offline
          } else {
           //online             
         }
    }
```

Comment: It was my bad, I was calling another method before checkConnection(); that method was trying to access the network. Thanks anyway